# Simple Highcharts chart not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, csv, firefox, highcharts

I am experiencing a strange issue with highcharts and Firefox. For some reason, this code works with Chrome, but not with Firefox:

```
var options = {
chart: {
    renderTo: 'visits',
    backgroundColor:null,
    type: 'line'
},
exporting: { enabled: false },
title: {
    text: 'Visits'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: [],
    tickInterval: 7,
    labels: {
        style: {
            fontSize:'8px'
        }}
},
yAxis: {
    labels: {
            enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: null
    }
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{point.y:.0f} Visits'
},
legend: {
    enabled: false
},
series: [{
    name: [],
    data: []
}]};
```

$.get('downloads/myfile.csv', function(data) {
    // Split the lines

```
var lines = data.split('\n');
$.each(lines, function(lineNo, line) {
    var items = line.split(',');
    if (lineNo !== 0) {
        options.series[0].data.push({
            name: items[0],
            y: parseFloat(items[1])
        });

        options.xAxis.categories.push(x);
    }
});
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); });
```

My CSV file has the following data:

```
2017-09-01,65
2017-09-02,36
2017-09-03,36
2017-09-04,91
2017-09-05,75
2017-09-06,120
```

Since items[1] is number, why it cannot be displayed in Firefox? If I replace items[1] with a plain number, say "1", I get a flat line which means that for some reason the parseFloat fails. I get no errors or warnings in the console.

How can I deal with this?

Comment: When you try to parseFloat a number 1 , how do you tried it ? 
like this : parseFloat(1) or like this : parseFloat("1")  ?

Comment: I do it like this:
parseFloat(items[1])

items[1] is supposed to be the second column of each line in the CSV.

I cannot understand why it works with Chrome and not with Firefox.
Replacing this:
y: parseFloat(items[1])
with
y: 1
results to a flat line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found why it did not work in firefox. The encoding of the CSV file is UTF-8 with BOM! For some reason Firefox cannot parse it. I have saved the CSV as ANSI and it works as expected. I guess I could resolve this by reading the file with AJAX.